# Angular - Variable is not updating on view inside two nested loops

Tags: angular, progress-bar, nested-loops, angular2-changedetection

I am trying to update the progress value in a 'round-robin' operation, but the % value is not updating in the view, but yes in the console.log().

I tried ngZone and the DetectorChanges method, but none worked.

I let you here the code. Thanks in advise.

```
   this.pageInfo.listPdfs.forEach((item,x) =>{
    this.pageInfo.listPdfs.forEach((item2,y) =>{
      if(x != y){
        let diff = jsdiff.diffWords(this.pageInfo.listPdfs[x].merged, this.pageInfo.listPdfs[y].merged)
        let removeds = diff.filter(el => el.removed == true).map(item => item.value).join(' ');
        let shared = diff.filter(el => el.removed === undefined && el.added === undefined).map(item => item.value).join(' ');
        let percent = (shared.trim().split(' ').filter(el => el != '').length / (removeds.trim().split(' ').filter(el => el != '').length + shared.trim().split(' ').filter(el => el != '').length)) * 100;
        this.pageInfo.resultsPdf.push({
          origin      : this.pageInfo.listPdfs[x], 
          destination : this.pageInfo.listPdfs[y],
          diff        : diff,
          percent     : percent
        })
        count++;
        this.ngZone.run(()=>{

        this.pageInfo.progressAnalyzer = (count / totalRevitions)*100; // <-- THIS NOT UPDATING ON TEMPLATE
        console.log(this.pageInfo.progressAnalyzer); // <-- THIS WORKS 
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

      });
        console.log(this.pageInfo.progressAnalyzer + '%');
      }
    })
  })
```

And in my view, it just a simply `{{pageInfo.progressAnalyzer}}` but never gets updated.

Comment: Why do you call detectChanges inside the for loops and not after they are finished?

Comment: For testing... doesen't work either.

Comment: What is your use case ?

Comment: I want to display the %progress, because it can take until 1 or 2 minutes.

Comment: @jotan you Can use subject rxjs

Comment: Where? In the whole function or just on the variable which I store the %?

Comment: I did It but didnt worked